# I have loaded wrong psql dump into my database, anyway to revert?

Tags: postgresql, restore

Ok, I screwed up.

I dumped one of my psql (9.6.18) staging database with the following command

```
pg_dump -U postgres -d <dbname> > db.out
```

And after doing some testing, I "restored" the data using the following command.

```
psql -f db.out postgres
```

Notice the absence of `-d` option?  yup. And that was supposed to be the username.

Annnd as the database happend to have the same name as its user, it overwrote the 'default' database (postgres), which had data that other QAs are using.

I cancelled the operation quickly as soon as I realised my mistake, but the damage was still done. Around 1/3 ~ 1/2 of the database is roughly identical to the staging database - at least in terms of the schema.

Is there any way to revert this? I am still looking for any other dumps if any of these guys made one. But I don't think there is any past two to three months. Seems like I got no choice but to own up and apologise to them in the morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a capture of the output of the `psql -f db.out postgres` run?

Since the pg_dump didn't specify `--clean` or `-c`, it should not have overwritten anything, just appended.  And if your tables have unique or primary keys, most of the data copy operations should have failed with unique key violations and rolled back.  Even one overlapping row (per table) would roll back the entire dataset for that table.

Without having the output, it will be hard to figure out what damage has actually been done.

You should also immediately copy the pg_xlog data someplace safe.  If it comes down to it, you might be able to use pg_xlogdump to figure out what changes committed and what did not.

Comment: Thank you, you are completely correct. The data was appended and the original table and its data were hidden down below. And since they had different owner, all I had to do was 'drop owned' operation and it went back to its previous state. What a relief. Thank you and in case I make this stupid mistake again,I will keep your advice in my mind. Have a great day!

Answer (score 3):

Without a recent dump or some sort of PITR replication setup, you can't un-revert this easily. The only option is to manually go through the log of what was restored and remove/alter it in the postgres database. This will work for the schema, the data is another matter. FYI, the postgres database should not really be used as a 'working' database. It is there to be a database to connect to for doing other operations, such as `CREATE DATABASE` or to bootstrap your way into a cluster. If left empty then the above would not have been a problem. You could have done, from another database, `DROP DATABASE postgres;` and then `CREATE DATABASE postgres`.

Comment: If postgres db wasn't there this wouldn't have been a problem. It is part of the legacy code and settings we have at work. I will see if I could change it.
Thank you.

Comment: You want to keep a database named "postgres" in the cluster as many tools, utilities, etc expect it to be there. You just want to leave it empty.  It also helps with situations like this where it is basically a throw away database that can be recreated at will.